# Add separator into toolbar in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019, right-click the toolbar area and choose `Customize`. Then on the `Commands` tab, select the `Toolbar` radio and choose one of the toolbars you have visible (say `Build`). Here you can add or change the order of commands.

In older versions of Visual Studio (eg. Visual Studio 2003), while in `Customize` mode you could grab and drag a button to insert a separator.

How do you add toolbar separators in Visual Studio 2019? In `Customize` mode, you cannot grab-and-drag buttons and I wasn't able to find any `Separator` option when I click `Add Command...`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In toolbar customization, if you select an item and click **Modify Selection**, you can check **Begin a Group** and it will add a separator above this item:

[image]

Comment: Works, thanks. Why hide this away, though...what was wrong with the "grab-and-drag" method that worked for decades or just a simple "Separator" command item you could add?